# "Press any key to continue . . ." prompt when Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, console

When I `Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5)` Visual Studio gives a helpful prompt at the end, giving me a chance to copy the console content etc.

Is there a switch to get this prompt when I do `Start Debugging (F5)`?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the last line of main().

Comment: I occasionally do things like if ( Debugger.IsAttached ) Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 0):

I wish I didn't have to remember to put a break-point every time but that seems to be the best available alternative.